# Optimizing an ActiveRecord query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, query-optimization

I have the following models and want to get all the available posts that **an specific user** has not put a like on them.

Post Model:

```rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :likes
  has_many :users, through: :likes

  scope :available, -> { where available: true }
end
```

Like Model:

```rb
class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user
end
```

User Model:

```rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :likes
  has_many :posts, through: :likes
end
```

I came up with this ActiveRecord query:

```rb
Post.available - Post.available.joins(:likes).where('likes.user_id = ?', user.id)
```

Is there an optimized way to achieve this? Maybe even an equivalent SQL query?

Comment: make a scope of `Post.available.joins(:likes).where('likes.user_id = ?', user.id)` and then substract

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved with:

```
Post.available.where("id not in (select post_id from likes where user_id = ?)", user.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

That could do it, I guess:

```
Post.available.where( 'NOT EXISTS (?)',
  user.likes.where('likes.post_id = posts.id')
)
```

You can also do this without SQL strings at all, like so:

```
Post.available.where(
  user.likes.where(post_id: Post.arel_table[:id]).exists.not
)
```

But I've seen constructs like this cause issues with parameter binding. I'm pretty sure it's a bug, but I'm not sure this trick is even in public ActiveRecord API (an so is ActiveRecord/Arel really to blame).

Answer (score -2):

Try this:-

```
Post.available.joins(:likes).where('likes.user_id NOT IN (?)', user.id)
```

Or you can add scope in post model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    scope :no_user_likes, ->(id) { joins(:likes).where('likes.user_id NOT IN (?)', id) }
end
```

Then you can call like:-

```
Post.available.no_user_likes(user.id)
```

Comment: Same issue as from the (now rightfully deleted) first answer: this fetches posts liked by **everyone but this user**. So the end result is wrong.